# Displaying data from database with AJAX, jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The model seems to be working as well as the controller. The AJAX displays the results as "null" so I think it is because we need to send the data as json. Any ideas on how to get the data into the correct format and to display in the view

**View**

```
<button type='button' name='getdata' id='getdata'>Get Data.</button>

<div id='result_table' style="color:white;">
hola amigo
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$('#getdata').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/index.php/trial/getValues',
                         type:'POST',
                         dataType: 'json',
                          error: function(){
                          $('#result_table').append('<p>goodbye world</p>');
                          },

                         success: function(results){


                       $('#result_table').append('<p>hello world</p>' +results);
                       alert("Success!");

                          } // End of success function of ajax form
                          }); // End of ajax call

                });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
function getValues(){
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data['results'] = $this->get_db->getAll();
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
    return $data;
}
```

**Model**

```
class Get_db extends CI_Model{
    function getAll(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
        return $query->result();
        //returns from this string in the db, converts it into an array
    }
}
```

Okay so the AJAX returns the success alert, however instead of displaying the table from the database, this is what is displays in the div:

Hello World

null

If I go directly to the url (http://loca.lhost:8888/index.php/trial/getValues)  this is the object that appears:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "qID": "1",
      "email": "hello",
      "qText": "hello",
      "playlistID": "",
      "timestamp": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "qID": "2",
      "email": "",
      "qText": "",
      "playlistID": "",
      "timestamp": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },

  }
```

How do I extract this info and display what I want to display?

Comment: Use `console.log(variable)` to get a good idea of your data returned. Also use a [json viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) for easy parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract data from the json by using `$.each`

```
success:function(data){
    $('#result_table').append('<p>hello world</p>');
    alert("Success!");
    $.each(data.results, function(k, v) {
        $.each(v, function(key, value) {
            $('#result_table').append('<br/>' + key + ' : ' + value);
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning `$data` from your controller, `json_encode` it and use `echo` instead.

```
function getValues(){
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data['results'] = $this->get_db->getAll();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. See the edit I have just made :)

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating some things, update this to just output json:

**controller:**

```
function getValues(){
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data['results'] = $this->get_db->getAll();

    if($data['result']){   // we got a result, output json
         echo json_encode( $data['result'] );
    } else {
         echo json_encode( array('error' => true) );
    }
}
```

and your **javascript** will easily handle the result (since you pass back JSON = javascript object notation)

```
success: function(data){
    // handle the result
    var re = $.parseJSON(data);

    if(!re.error){
        // no error so lets put out some data whatever way
    }
}
```

Using `var re = $.parseJSON(data);` will easily let you access the json data in `.` form:

`re.result` etc;

Output the json to `console.log(data)` to see its structure (without printing it into your html). Use Chrome inspector to traverse your structure.